# Opening and editing a very large mySQL database

Tags: mysql, database, file

I have a database that's 1,300,000 KB large that was backed up and saved locally a month or so ago.

Well, the version hosted on the old server was getting hacked. Somehow, additional data (posts, users) were being added to it taking it over the maximum file-size threshold. As a result, the database corrupted and was erased.

I still have my local copy and I'm rebuilding the database on a new server. The problem is that the new server has a similar date file-size threshold and the database is too large because it has all this extra spam data in it.

Therefore, I need to edit it locally, deleting the unnecessary data, then uploaded.

I've tried opening the file in: Sublime, NotePad, WordPad, mySQL Workbench, Vim...to no avail.

I was finally able to open it in Microsoft Visual Studio using the mySQL Workbench plugin...

However, the program won't let me 1) edit the file 2) or copy and paste any of the data elsewhere...It results in a "system out of memory" notification....

Does anyone have experience working with large mySQL database files? What applications/programs to you suggest I use to open and edit this file locally?

Comment: this file is raw sql from `mysqldump`, or it's the actual binary data files from mysql? no one can help you directly editing the binary files. the raw dump is just text, and if you can find a text editor that can handle a 1.3gig text file, then go to it.

Comment: When you say "MySQL database file" do you mean the file used by MySQL to hold your data? What's the name of the file (I ask because I'm trying to figure out what kind of file it is.) Can you please give the table definition of at least one of the large tables you're trying to recover (to reveal the access method you're using)?

Comment: It's a .SQL file. I downloaded it from PHPMyAdmin

Answer (score 0):

Install MySQL locally, load the dump, prune what you don't want and dump it again. 1.3 GB limit on the database, you might want to look at a new hosting solution...